# Pandas missing values : fill with the closest non NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, nan, fillna

Assume I have a pandas series with several consecutive NaNs. I know `fillna` has several methods to fill missing values (`backfill` and `fill forward`), but I want to fill them with the closest non NaN value. Here's an example of what I have:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3])
```

And an example of what I want:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3])
```

Does anyone know I could do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the series contain only one part with consecutive NaNs or could there possibly be multiple parts (e.g. `[0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3]`)?

Comment: @a_guest It can contain multiple parts

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use [`Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) with `method='nearest'`:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3])

In [12]: s.interpolate(method='nearest')
Out[12]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
6    3.0
dtype: float64

In [13]: s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3])

In [14]: s.interpolate(method='nearest')
Out[14]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    3.0
dtype: float64
```